# setSelectedItemChoice selected to only one item in dialog instead of click item android

Tags: android, dialog

```
public void showDialog(Activity activity) {
        final CharSequence[] items = {" No timer ", " 1 minute ", " 3 minute ", " 5 minute ", "10 minute"};

// Creating and Building the Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AutumnForest.this);
        builder.setTitle("Set timer duration");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selection, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        if (isRunning) {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            _tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            gong_imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            timer_imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_icon);
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // if timer is running somewhere
                        if (!isRunning) {
                            isRunning = true;
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (!isRunning) {
                            isRunning = true;
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (!isRunning) {
                            isRunning = true;
                            countDownTimer(item);
                        } else {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (!isRunning) {
                            isRunning = true;
                            countDownTimer(item);
                        } else {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:                       
                        if (!isRunning) {
                            isRunning = true;
                            countDownTimer(item);
                        } else {
                            count_down_timer.cancel();
                            countDownTimer(item);
                            levelDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(AutumnForest.this, "Something went wrong please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
        });
        levelDialog = builder.create();
        levelDialog.show();
    }
```

code working well but when click happen it stays to case 1 instead of clicked item.
 i want that the if i clicked on case 3 or 4 something like that it should be setchecked = true and other else setchecked = false but it is not showing.

[image: here is the output which i am getting]

here is the output which i am getting.

Comment: What is 1 in `setSingleChoiceItems(items, 1,.....`

Comment: 1 is initially checked item position. when dialog open first time case 1 will be selected default.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
switch (item) {
       case item[0]:
       case item[1]:
                   ...........
```

Comment: Trace the logcat when you press 3 or 5 minute and update I can help

Comment: array automatically count howmany item are in array and according to that position assign. in my array there will be position like 0,1,2,3

Comment: but atleast trace the logcat to know whats going on when u press 3 or 5

Comment: i tried. i also get the which item clicked but i am not able to set true which button is click.

Comment: @NiteshRathod dude are u out of mind, please add proper code to think of. Everything is wrong in ur code, u missing array, braces. How do u expect a developer to answer after seeing your code. Upload fresh and correct one.